# Why can't the child override an event subscription in its parent?

Tags: c#, events, inheritance

Here's a sample code that won't work as I expected when using virtual methods and overrides. Why?

```
main()
{
    Child c = new Child();
    c.Trigger = new Trigger();
}

public class Parent
{
    public Trigger _trigger;

    public Trigger Trigger
    {
        set 
        {
            _trigger = value;
            _trigger.TriggerEvent += Trigger.TriggerHandler(OnTrigger);
        }
    }

    internal virtual void OnTrigger(int type)
    {
        Write("I don't want to write this!");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    internal override void OnTrigger(int type)
    {
        Write("I want this to be written, but it's not.");
    }
}
```

The method "OnTrigger" that subscribes to the event in the parent is not overridden. How to make an event that is subscribed upon in the parent execute the child's method?

Comment: It works fine for me... Is this your actual code?

Comment: Please include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (example that demonstrates the problem).

Comment: No, it's not my actual code, I removed unnecessary parts and renamed for simplicity. But the principle is the same

Answer (score 0):

Is the following code is what you want?

```
    public class Trigger
    {
        public event Action TriggerEvent;

        public void NotifyTrigger()
        {
            this.TriggerEvent();
        }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public Trigger _trigger;

        public Trigger Trigger
        {
            get
            {
                return _trigger;
            }

            set
            {
                _trigger = value;
                _trigger.TriggerEvent += this.OnTrigger;
            }
        }

        internal virtual void OnTrigger()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("I don't want to write this!");
        }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        internal override void OnTrigger()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("I want this to be written, but it's not.");
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void testetst() // Or Main
    {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.Trigger = new Trigger();
        c.Trigger.NotifyTrigger();
    }
```

It is working for me. The output is: "I want this to be written, but it's not."

Comment: Yes, I haven't really tested the example until now, and yes, it works for me too. I guess I have to check if there is anything else I've missed in the real code. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem elsewhere. In this case Child1.Trigger should affect the Child child instance, but instead of calling child.Trigger.NotifyTrigger() (using Yohanes' example) it called its own (this.Trigger.NotifyTrigger) Child1 had not overridden the OnTrigger!